# Typescript: call method from another method inside a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to Typescript. I want to call method `doSomething` of class `Maincontroller` at the end of `initialiseMap`. I get an error if I use `this` and when I call it using `MainController.prototype.doSomething($scope,'Test')` nothing seems to happen.

```
class MainController {

constructor($http, $scope, $timeout, socket) {
    // some code
    this.initialiseMap($scope, $timeout);
}

initialiseMap($scope, $timeout){
    // some more code
    // I need to call doSomething($scope,'Test') from here
}

doSomething ($scope, smth) {
   // even more code
}
}
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: What error do you get? Do you really call the initializeMap in the context of a MainController instance?

Answer (score 0):

On my computer that works perfectly well. To be sure, try this code :

```
class MainController {
    constructor($http, $scope, $timeout, socket) {
        // some code
        this.initialiseMap($scope, $timeout);
    }

    initialiseMap($scope, $timeout){
        // some more code
        // I need to call doSomething($scope,'Test') from here
        console.log($scope, $timeout);
    }

    doSomething ($scope, smth) {
        // even more code
    }
}
```

And create an instance, this will display you the value of `$scope` and `$timeout`.